# Слайдер в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Интересует такой момент с tkinter ,scale widget если воспользоваться методом get () возвращает текущию позицию . Но вопрос в том что возвращает её и все передвижения (то есть если слайдер шёл с 0 до 10 вернёт все последовательность)есть ли какой то способ получить только последние значение со слайдера?

Comment: Добавьте пример вашего кода

Comment: Ответ скрыт в точном определении термина "последнее значение".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scal = Scale(root,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=300,from_=0,to=100,tickinterval=10,resolution=5)
```

`orient` - это как будет расположен widget, HORIZONTAL - горизонтально, VERTICAL - вертикально

`from_` - это с какого числа начинается шкала

`to` - это до какого числа заканчивается шкала

`resolution` - это интервал, например если `form_=0, to=100, resolution = 20`, то ползунок будет перемещаться только по 20 пунктов, и будет иметь всего 5 положений (это положение: 20,40,60,80,100), так как 20*5=100

Чтобы получить значение сразу же, делаем `bind`:

```
sca.bind("<B1-Motion>",func1)
```

А в функции прописываем:

```
def func(event):
    s1 = scal.get()

    if s1 == 10:
        print("Number 10")
    if s1 == 20:
        print("Number 20")
```

---

Вот пример получения значений 3 способами:

```
from tkinter import*

def get_val_command(s1):
    print("Command Number",str(s1))

def get_val_bind(event):
    s1 = scal.get()
    print("Get Number",str(s1))

def get_val_motion(event):
    s1 = scal.get()
    print("Motion Number",str(s1))

root = Tk()

# 1 способ
scal = Scale(root,orient=VERTICAL ,length=300,from_=0,to=100,tickinterval=10,resolution=10)
scal.bind("<B1-Motion>",get_val_motion)
scal.pack()

# 2 способ
but1 = Button(text="Get through bind")
but1.bind("<Button-1>",get_val_bind)
but1.pack()

# 3 способ
but2 = Button(text="Get through command", command=lambda:get_val_command(scal.get()))
but2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```